# How to print this in one line statement in Prolog

Tags: printing, prolog, swi-prolog

How can i print this string in prolog in the best way:

```
predicate([], L, Id, L2):-
   length(L2, N),
   write('The length '),
   write(Id),
   write(' is '),
   write(N),
   write(' elements.'),
   nl.
```

Comment: It is by no means clear what you mean by string. And in general, avoid to do explicit writing, instead, formulate your program in such a way that the answers at the top level are just the printing you need.

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog forum [Best practices for printing](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/best-practices-for-printing/4231)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use the built-in predicate [format/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2):

```
predicate([], L, Id, L2):-
   length(L2, N),
   format('The length of ~w is ~w elements\n', [Id, N]).
```

Comment: it was exactly what i needed. ty!!